# plt.tight_layout() with sns.clustermap

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Seaborns clustermap doesn't work with plt.tight_layout().

```
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(98)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,10))
cm = sns.clustermap(df)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

gives the following error `ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence`.
I've also used `sns.heatmap()` with the exact same data set and this gave no errors. Is there a work around?
Note: The actual labels I'm using are a lot longer than the ones in this example but the codes too long to show. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Another part of the error is the message:

> This figure includes Axes that are not compatible with tight_layout, so its results might be incorrect.

I don't think `tight_layout` works with `clustermap`. However, from the [`sns.clustermap` documentation](http://stanford.edu/%7Emwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.clustermap.html), it says that:

> The returned object has a savefig method that should be used if you want to save the figure object without clipping the dendrograms.

So, in your example, you could use `cm.savefig('myfigure.png')`, which seems to perform similar actions to `tight_layout`.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error when I placed the `plt.tight_layout()` before the `plt.plot()` and `plt.xlabel()` I just had to move it to the last command before `plt.show()` and it worked.